# Trying to install apache web server Linux Ubuntu

Tags: server, apache2, nginx

I trying to install apache web server with this command

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

nd get this message

```
Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5) but it is not going to be installed
   Depends: apache2-utils (>= 2.4)
   Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5) but it is not going to be installed 
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Does anyone knows what is happening and how to install?
I get same output wit i try to install Nginx.

Comment: Can you add the output of `apt policy apache2 apache2-bin apache2-utils apache2-data mysql-server mysql-server-5.7` to your question? Most likely you have added an unofficial software source to your system which provides newer but incompatible versions of some packages.

Answer (score 1):

Try `apt install -f` 
**Or**
Try using `apt` instead of `apt-get`. Apt will likely give you a fix.

Also have you done `apt update && apt upgrade` before installing apache2.